# ng build --prod is not generating vendor.bundle.js

Tags: angular, ng-build

I am using node version 8.9.4,
npm version 5.6.0 I have no clue why this is happening the
`ng build --dev` is generating vendor.bundle.js while `ng build --prod` is not generating vendor.bundle.js here is the screenshot

**output with ng build--prod**
[[image]
**[output with ng-build --dev]** 
   [image]

Here is my package.json

```
`{
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.28",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

`

Comment: It's normal and expected. The prod build tries to optimize your bundle as much as possible, and one of these optimizations is more effective if you don't split your app between two bundles.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For prod builds the vendor bundle is integrated in your main bundle, because it is using the build optimizer per default.

According to the [angular-cli documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds):

> Total bundle sizes with Build Optimizer are smaller if there is no separate vendor chunk because having vendor code in the same chunk as app code makes it possible for Uglify to remove more unused code.

Answer (score 18):

ng build by default don't generate vendor-chunk but instead it is combined in one main-chunk for performance and optimization purposes, you will need to add a parameter to the build command like so in order to have your vendor-chunk separated:
`ng build --prod --vendor-chunk=true`

see details here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--build-optimizer-and---vendor-chunk