# Angular 6 'ng build --prod' is not minifying/uglifying the index.html

Tags: angular

In Angular 6, when i ran the **ng build prod**, i see change from angular 4 that, it is not Minification or uglification the index.html and also i didn't see **vendor.js** after running the above mentioned command.

Is there any documentation available where i can go through changes done in Angular 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369010/ng-build-prod-is-not-generating-vendor-bundle-js) SO question.

Comment: But that does not contain information about index.html and documentation i am asking about..

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11360. Regarding the changes: both the CLI and Angular github projects have a changelog (as a changelog.md file, or as guthub releases). And there are dozens of blog posts covering the changes.

Comment: @MANJITKUMAR please edit the header to clarify the requirement.